# How to retain a process in FLASK even after the browser is closed and loaded to the previous page?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, celery, task

I have a flask endpoint `"/progress"` which checks for  values in **DB** for progress to be displayed in the frontend. This endpoint is continuously called until the progress becomes **100%.**

```
@app.route("/progress")

def check_progress():

    # function returns the current progress from DB
    progress_in_percentage = progress_value()

    return progress_in_percentage


@app.route("/home_page")

def load_home_page_details():
    # funtion return the users home page projects from DB
    home = load_projects_home()

    return home
```

The problem arises when the user ***accidentally closes the browser***  where the calculation was happening and ***open the page application again***. *The Flask shutdowns the progress process and loads the home page*.

***How can I retain the progress process even after the user closes the browser come backs to the page ? Plus the solution should be scalable for many users***.

I am using `python3.7` in the backend and `Flask` to serve the requests.